# jquery mouseup ensure firing only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am confuse about how to make sure the mouseup firing only once.

```
function cropPet(){
  $("#canvas").on("mouseup", function(){
    console.log("hello world");
  });
}
```

for example `cropPet` function got fired when I click a button 3 times, everytime i `mouseup` on the #canvas i got 3 times hello world in my console. i have tried to append `off()` before the `on()` but it doesn't work, no `hello world` at all in my console (not firing?). here is my script with `off()` attached.

```
function cropPet(){
  $("#canvas").off("mouseup").on("mouseup", function(){
    console.log("hello world");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) which will ensure the event only fires once:

```
$("#canvas").one("mouseup", function(){
    console.log("hello world");
});
```

Form the jQuery documentation:

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

Comment: i tried this, same result as i attach the off before on. i will upload the whole things, so you can get idea what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function cropPet(){
  $("#canvas").on("mouseup", function(){
    console.log("hello world");
    $("#canvas").off("mouseup");
  });
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLzF6/).

Answer (score 0):

You have a conceptual error in your script. Your function `cropPet()` defines a click-listener on `$("#canvas")` when executed. So when you execute that function 3 times, 3 click-listener and therefore 3 times the alert-message are being executed each time you click that element.

Now what you want is to directly assign the click-listener to the element:

```
function cropPet(){
    console.log("hello world");
}
$("#canvas").on("mouseup", function(){
    cropPet();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the event to only fire once during the lifetime of the app? In that case, you might want to do something like this:

```
//Function to remove the event
function removeMouseEvent(item) {
    $(item).off();
}

//Attach The Event
$("#canvas").on("mouseup", function () {
    console.log("hello world");
    removeMouseEvent(this);
});
```

Here is a fiddle showing the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/amspianist/Dc6tb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the event propagation so the function fire only once

```
 $("#canvas").on("mouseup", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("hello world");
 });
```